# Disable process running on boot

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I see a process running on system boot,  don't want it to run on the boot, I was trying to find a service starting it, but there is no such service, I looked at msconfig.com to find maybe it is on startup list programs, but it is not there. How can I find who starts it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to identify which programs and services are launched on startup. It scans through all possible locations where the startup can be registered.